# Dalvik-vm Out Of Memory while appending string with StringBuilder

Tags: android

My App receives image data from server as XML. During paring the XML, I append the data using StringBuilder, decode the image data and then display the image. If the image size is greater than 1MB, I get Dalvik-vm "Out Of Memory' exception as below:

```
07-16 19:23:35.376: E/dalvikvm-heap(374): Out of memory on a 10501076-byte allocation.
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405e3238 self=0x38ff88
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   | sysTid=434 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3735744
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   | schedstat=( 3989536323 3728953745 437 )
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~95)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:153)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at os.android.lib.asgsuitesdk.XmlReader.characters(XmlReader.java:121)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:165)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.appendBytes(Native Method)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:518)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
07-16 19:23:35.376: I/dalvikvm(374):   at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:390)
```

Is there anyway, I can get rid of this exception? I know, depends on the device, the heap memory allocated for an Android app is minimum 16MB. In my case, the image size is between 1MB ~ 2MB and it crashes. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
DK

Comment: You gotta check your code for another memory leaks cause allocating 1Mb should not be the problem.

Comment: Look at your exception message. It says "Out of memory on a 10501076-byte allocation." It tries to allocate 10 MB, not 2 or 3 MB.

Answer (score -1):

You have to downsample your image. Remember that an image will use approximately `H x W x 4 bytes` of memory to be displayed, so the "file size" does not really reflect the actual size in memory. You have to downsample the image so that it's only as big as it needs to for it to fit in the screen.

See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012548/view-paging-with-lots-of-images-can-it-even-work/10013071#10013071)